# dynamic url in ajax

Tags: php, ajax, csv

I try to plot graphs from data.csv

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.csv",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {processData(data);}
    });
```

full html code is [here](http://canvasjs.com/forums/topic/graph-a-csv-file/#post-6371)

But I have to create data.csv using user given arguments. Which I am taking through the form get method.

```
<form action="/test.php" >
<input type="text" name="starttime" placeholder="starttime " >
```

In my php script I use

```
$time=$_GET['starttime'];
shell_exec("bash myscript.sh $time > data.csv");
```

I intend to make the graph from this newly created csv. However I am unable to

1. give dynamic url, i.e. same as file name created by shell script. Also, there is a chance of generating many files on server , is there a way to do this cleanly.
2. Let php invoke the plot and display the graph

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling your `data.csv` file you should call a PHP file which will render your fresh CSV file.

HTML :

```
<form id="yourForm">
<input type="text" name="starttime" placeholder="starttime " >
</form>
```

Javascript :

```
$('#yourForm').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "last-csv-file.php?starttime="+$form.find('input[name="starttime"]').val(),
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {processData(data);}
    });
});
```

And `last-csv-file.php` :

```
$time=$_GET['starttime'];

// Write the CSV in a temporary file
$tmpFileName = tempnam('/tmp', 'a-prefix-of-your-choice');
shell_exec("bash myscript.sh $time > $tmpFileName");

// Get the content of your tmp CSV file and remove it
$csvContent = file_get_contents($tmpFileName);
unlink($tmpFileName);

// Display that content with the proper mimetype
header('content-type: text/csv');
echo $content;
exit;
```

Be aware of something: you may have a serious security issue with that line `shell_exec("bash myscript.sh $time > data.csv");` If the user type something like that in the field "&& rm -Rf ./" (or any kind of command) it could break your server. You should always check `starttime` contains a date and nothing else.

Comment: How do i take starttime from user now? and in the php script you used echo content, does that goes like data(formal argument of function)

Comment: I updated the message with a simple way to trigger the ajax request when the user submit the form (with javascript). I didn't understand the last part of your message "does that goes like data(formal argument of function)", can you reformulate it (sorry english is not my primary lang).

Comment: Thanks @Raphael but, this doesnt seem to invoke the script. I added <input type="submit" value="PLOT"> to form. But on clicking PLOT(submit). The control never reaches the javascript on clicking PLOT